# Resize figures - Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, circuitikz

Can I resize this picture in `Beamer`?

```
\begin{frame}     
\begin{figure}[width=0.2\textwidth]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt]

\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}

\draw (0,0) node[op amp,rotate = 90] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.-) to [short,-*] ++(-2,0) coordinate (CMm)
    to [short,-] ++(0,-1)
    to node[npn,anchor=emitter,yscale = -1] (Q1){} node[right,yshift = -0.7cm] {$Q_1$} ++(0,-1)

    (opamp.+) to [short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate (CMp)
    to [R,l=$R_1$] ++(0,-1.5)
    to node[npn,anchor=emitter,yscale = -1,xscale = -1] (Q2){} node[left,yshift = -0.7cm] {$Q_2$} ++(0,0)

    (Q1.base) |- (Q1.collector)
    (Q2.base) |- (Q2.collector)

    (CMp) to [short,-] ++(0,3)
    to node[pmos,anchor=drain,yscale = 1,xscale = 1] (M2){} node[right,yshift = 0.7cm] {$M_2$} ++(0,1)

    (CMm) to [short,-] ++(0,3)
    to node[pmos,anchor=drain,yscale = 1,xscale = -1] (M1){} node[left,yshift = 0.7cm] {$M_1$} ++(0,1)

    (M1.gate) to [short,-,l = $oa\_out$] (M2.gate)
    (M1.source) to [short,-,l = $VDD$] (M2.source)
    (opamp.out) to [C,l=$C_{16}$] ++(0,1) |- (M2.gate)

    (Q1.collector) |- (Q2.collector) node[ground] {}

 ;

\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Basic voltage reference}
\label{fig:basic}
\end{figure} 

\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Next time, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really `figure` doesn't do anything in `beamer`, it's like having a `center` environment.

To scale the graphic, you can use two ways:

1. use `scale` with `transform shape` (both are Ti*k*Z options):

   ```
   \begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt, scale=0.7, transform shape]
   ```
2. use a `scalebox` --- this will work also with different x- and y-scale, while the former will fail for `circuitikz` (see the manual at the section "known bugs and limitations"): You wrap your circuit like that:

   ```
   \scalebox{0.8}[0.7]{%
        \begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt]
         ...
         \end{circuitikz}%
   }
   ```